# How do I retrieve the entire conversation based on the initial tweet ID?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I'm looking for the simplest, most elegant implementation for this, preferably in pure JS/Node. Ideally, this is a function that is fed the tweet ID and returns a JSON object of the entire conversation. I'm aware of possible implementations using dedicated scrapers or automation tools, but I'd like to have a solution that's short, sweet, and pure JS. Anyone has any idea how to do this elegantly?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about getting the continuing conversation but you can get the previous tweets using Node.

If you make a GET request to https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/lookup.json (Documentation can be read here https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/lookup) as part of the JSON response it will return an object with a key `in_reply_to_status_id`. You pass this back to the GET request you just made to `status/lookup.json` with the value of `in_reply_to_status_id` until the value is null. The object will also have `text` key which you can get the content of the tweet from.

An example of the endpoint you would use would be: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/lookup.json?id=432656548536401920